# Function overloading inside overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I am using `C++14` (and pretty new to it). I have 3 overloaded functions `func` within which another overloaded function `do_something` gets called depending on its parent function (`func`).

```
int func(int a) {
   bar(a);
   foo();
 }

int func(int a, float b) {
   bar(a);
   do_something(b);
   foo();
}

int func(int a, float b, char c) {
   bar(a);
   do_something(b, c);
   foo();
 }
```

I see that the functionality within `func` is almost the same except which version of `do_something` gets called. Is there any way I can make this generic and combine all `func`'s together?

Comment: You could possibly use [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) but it might be harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, make `func` a template that accepts a parameter pack. The `int a` argument, the call to `bar` and the call to `foo` are always there, so that's simple. Let's add a placeholder for `do_something` for now.

```
template <class ...Args>
int func(int a, Args&&... other)
{
   bar(a);
   // somehow call do_something and do the right thing
   foo();

   return 0;
}
```

You want to instantiate and invoke the above template as before:

```
func(42);
func(42, 1.f);
func(42, 1.f, 'A');
```

Now let's tackle the call to `do_something`. If you simply add it in the middle of the new `func` template;

```
do_something(std::forward<Args>(other)...);
```

this refuses to compile for `func(42)`, i.e., the case with only one argument. Hence, we need a special case for this. One way to achieve this in another level of indirection for `do_something`:

```
// No additional argument case, does nothing:
void do_something_wrapper() {}

// The other two cases    
template <class ...Args>
void do_something_wrapper(Args&&... args)
{
   do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And now, the placeholder from the `func` function template should be:

```
do_something_wrapper(std::forward<Args>(other)...);
```

Comment: Instead of creating a wrapper, can't I have  `void do_something() {}`?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely an option. I thought you want to leave the `do_something` overload set as it is, but if you adjust it like that, you get rid of the wrapper indirection.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to use variadic-templates to take the part you want to forward to `do_something`:

```
template<class ... Args>
int func(int a, Args... args)
{
   bar(a);
   do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
   foo();
}
```

But now you have lost the argument types of func. So if this is a problem you will have to find a way to test them again.

Comment: Could use `std::is_invocable` (C++17) or just SFINAE with `std::invoke_result` to regain type checking.

Comment: `std::forward`ing something that is not a forwarding reference is not gonna achieve much. Also, if the OP doesn't have a `do_something(void)` this will fail, so you need to account for it with a fallback.

Comment: @StoryTeller Or use `constexpr if` to not do the call if `sizeof... args == 0`.

Comment: @Botje - Not in C++14

Answer (score 1):

Although I would probably go with the answer from generic_opto_guy myself, he's right to point out that you would lose the types in your interface. Depending on your situation, you might want to preserve this.

In that case, you can easily rework it to something akin to the following:

```
namespace details {

template<class ... Args>
int func_impl(int a, Args &&... args)
{
   bar(a);
   do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
   foo();
}

}

int func(int a) { return details::func_impl(a); }

int func(int a, float b) { return details::func_impl(a, b); }

int func(int a, float b, char c) { return details::func_impl(a, b, c); }
```

Note that the implementation has been adjusted to use [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). While not required in this particular case, it is often useful in forwarding situations you might encounter in the future.

Again, unless you absolutely need to present a clear interface to client code, I would just go with the first implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good general purpose answers to the question as asked, but if you have a few "spare" values of `c` available, you could write something like:

```
int func(int a) {
   func(a, 0.0,'\001');
}

int func(int a, float b, char c = '\002') {
   bar(a);
   switch (c) {
   case '\001':
      break;              // func(a)
   case '\002':
      do_something(b):    // func(a, b)
      break;
   default:
      do_something(b, c); // func(a, b, c)
      break;
   }
   foo();
}
```

Depending on the application, this may be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Is too late to play?

You tagged C++14 but, if you could use C++17, you could use `if constexpr` so

```
template <typename ... Ts>
int func (int a, Ts && ... ts)
 {
   bar(a);

   if constexpr ( sizeof...(Ts) > 0u )
      do_something(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);

   foo();

   // and remember to return something of int
 }
```

In C++14 you have to duplicate something somewhere.

Or you write two `func()`s

```
int func (int a)
 {
   bar(a);    
   foo();

   // and remember to return something of int
 }


template <typename ... Ts>
int func (int a, Ts && ... ts)
 {
   bar(a);

   do_something(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);

   foo();

   // and remember to return something of int
 }
```

or you add a no-argument `do_something()`

```
void do_something ()
 { }
```

or, as suggested by lubgr, you call `do_something()` through a wrapper (creating a special no-argument wrapper).

Comment: Does `constexpr` statement "executed" at compile time? If that is the case, it will be a problem. And I'm forced to stick to C++14 because of the distro of the library I am using.

Comment: @harsh - `if constexpr`, not simply `constexpr`. It's a pity you can't use C++17 because should be perfect for you. The test is evaluated compile-time (in this case works because `sizeof...(Ts) > 0u` is evaluable compile-time) and the following instruction (`do_something(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);`) is compiled iff (if and only if) the test is true. In C++14 I don't see a way without duplicating something.

Comment: Evaluating it at compile-time might be an issue, because in this case, the arguments get populated at run-time. But I need to rethink this if it is really the case.

Comment: @harsh - Suggestion: give it a try, if you can. If the test is based over the **number** of arguments, can't be a problem because (it's C++) the number of arguments is necessarily known compile time.